# Js/Jquery injection script for swagger not running on IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having problems with this code not running on IE11 and I cant figure out what is wrong. I'm totally new to both java scrip and Jquery and this is an extension script for my swagger in Net. Web Api.

Basicly what it does: It adds 2 new selects with API Group/Version. Everything runs fine on the chrome.

```
(function (){
var DiscoveryUrlSelector = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function ()
    {
        // Nerenderuj opakovanÄ na reloadu
        var defaultVal = this.$el.val()
        if (!this.$el.find('#input_' + this.options.name).length) {

            var container = $('<div class="input"></div>');
            var select = $('<select id="input_' + this.options.name + '" name="' + this.options.name + '"></select>');
            select
                .css('border', '1px solid gray')
                .css('padding', '3px')
                .css('width', '100px')
                .css('font-size', '0.9em');

            _.each(this.options.discoveryPaths, function (path)
            {
                var option = $('<option>' + path + '</option>');
                select.append(option);
            });

            select.val(defaultVal);

            if (this.options.name == 'Group')
                select.change(LoadVersionsForGroup);

            select.change(SetVersionedGroup);
            container.append(select);
            $("#api_selector > div:nth-child(2)").after(container);
        }    
        return this;
    }
});

new DiscoveryUrlSelector(
    {
        el: $('#api_selector'),
        name: 'Version',
        rootUrl: swashbuckleConfig.rootUrl,
        discoveryPaths: Array.from(new Set(swashbuckleConfig.discoveryPaths.map(x => x.substring(x.lastIndexOf("v"), x.length))))
    }).render();

new DiscoveryUrlSelector(
    {
        el: $('#api_selector'),
        name: 'Group',
        rootUrl: swashbuckleConfig.rootUrl,
        discoveryPaths: Array.from(new Set(swashbuckleConfig.discoveryPaths.map(x => x.substring(13, x.lastIndexOf("v")))))
    }).render();

function LoadVersionsForGroup()
{
    $('#input_Version option').each(function () {$(this).remove();});

    var versions = unique(swashbuckleConfig.discoveryPaths.filter(x => (x) => { return $("#input_Group").val() === x.substring(13, x.lastIndexOf("v")) }).map(x => x.substring(x.lastIndexOf("v"), x.length)))

    _.each(versions, function (path)
    {
        var option = $('<option>' + path + '</option>');
        $('#input_Version').append(option);
    });
}

function SetVersionedGroup(){
    $("#input_baseUrl").val(swashbuckleConfig.rootUrl + "/swagger/docs/" + $("#input_Group").val() + $("#input_Version").val())
}

function unique(list) {
    var result = [];
    $.each(list, function (i, e) {
        if ($.inArray(e, result) == -1) result.push(e);
    });
    return result;
}})();
```

EDIT:
Also there are no errors in dev tools, the elements just dont render. I also have an another Jquery script that does add Basic Auth controls and it works just fine.
Screen:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end the problem was in the '=>' arrow functions that dont run in IE 11.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most important things that you'll learn with JS and Web Development in general, is that not all browsers are up to date. IE is notorious for this. You can negate this by using a different method or more commonly using a [pollyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Polyfill). Anytime you notice an issue with something working in chrome but not firefox, look over what methods you're using and check their support.

There are several good resources for checking browser compatibility. caniuse.com or developer.mozilla.org (I highly recommend using MDN, it's a great resource on learning JS and web dev in general)

You can also run chrome in compatibility mode to test this ([see how here](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-change-Google-Chrome-compatibility-mode))

All that being said - Nothing jumps out to me with your jquery, but it looks like there is potentially an issue with compatibility in the Swashbuckle library. A quick google search is showing a lot of issues with swagger in IE11 as well. [Check out this thread](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3540) to see if it's relevant to what you're experiencing. This is closed so it may not be quite right, but that's my initial suspicion.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well I have another scripts written in Jquery and they run just fine even in the IE, so it must something with this one. Also in the dev tools inside IE, I get no errors, the elements just dont render.